# How can I apply a policy to homepage in Sails?

Tags: sails.js, sails-permissions

I want to apply a policy that lets user to login to application. I written the code for policy. I want to apply this one to homepage also.

I tried below in policies.js but its not working on homepage.

```
'*' : 'isLoggedIn'
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want apply the policy to homepage

you must do it into the file route.js

```
 '/': {
    view: 'homepage',policy: 'isLoggedIn'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not serving your homepage through a controller/action. Policies can only be applied to content which get served via controller/action.

From the documentation of [Sails Policies](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) :

> Policies in Sails are versatile tools for authorization and access
>   control-- they let you allow or deny access to your controllers down
>   to a fine level of granularity.

It should start working once you serve the homepage via a controller.

Comment: Thanks for the response I added  '/' in route.js with a controller to handle its working. But I was thinking if there is a way to handle policy for the views directly.

Comment: @MaheshB No, there is no way you can handle policy for views directly. Atleast as of the current version. :)

Comment: @MaheshB Please accept the answer if its working fine